# Flash charts that can map/dither the data on X axis

Tags: database, flash, charts

I looked at different flash chart software (free and commercial) and could find only one that supports the feature I want: map my dataset on the predefined X axis. Let me give an example.

Let's say my X axis is time. The time is represented in hours. So let's assume my X axis has last 24 hours. Now the data I have in the database contains data coming every 50 minutes. My goal is to have a chart that will show this data. The point on the graph will not correspond to X axis values one to one.

The simple solution (and all charts support this) is to set X axis resolution to 1 minute and only show "ticks" on A axis every hour. Assuming that chart supports "null" values (and most of them are) - it works fine as an idea.

The problem is that in this case (for all of the charts I know) I have to provide XML/json/CSV as a source of data that will contain 24 hours * 60 minutes points of data, with only ~29 (24 hours, every 50min) containing meaningful data. This puts a stress on 1) database, 2) more traffic 3) makes chart less responsive.

Are there any flash graphs that will accept a dataset of ~29 values and map into 24 points on X axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[amCharts Stock Chart](http://www.amcharts.com/stock) can have a date/time x-axis which is just a linear date/time axis (doesn't have to come from your data). There's a setting for that called equal_spacing=false (as far as I remember).

[Here's](http://www.amcharts.com/stock/data-at-irregular-intervals/) the feature in action.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using amCharts Stock Chart.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, OpenFlashChart has can draw this, it's called "ScatterLine".
We use [DZ branch](http://ofc2dz.com/), it fixes a problem with X axis labels that can also be scattered.

Though, beware to exceed a 32-bit integer limit. It can't handle 64bit X values.

Comment: Well, OFC2 is what I'm using right now and I didn't want to consider it as an option at all. Multiple reasons: lack of debug, support, lot's of bugs, etc. I'll check DZ Branch - was not aware of it. Maybe it will solve many problems I had with it.

Comment: It did for us. Still, it's somewhat buggy, but does the simple charting we needed.